# Insertion into a table on two different conditions SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to order a table's entries by the difference in time (so end_g - start_g). However, there is a possibility that there is no end time (still ongoing). Below is the code I wrote to try to insert with a conditional; if there is an end then take the difference between start and end time, else take the difference from currtime() and start time. From this, I want to select the name from 'artist' that has the longest time after this sorting.

```
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE name = (SELECT group FROM members WHERE end IS NOT NULL ORDER BY DATEDIFF (millisecond, end_g, start_g) OR end IS NULL ORDER BY DATEDIFF(millisecond, GETDATE(), start_g) AND ROWNUM = 1);
```

Currently the error says that I have unbalanced parentheses, but I suspect it is something from with the way I construct this first SELECT statement. Any suggestions?

Comment: `datediff` or `getdate` functions don't belong to Oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

no need order by inside subquery and i prefer `in` rather =

```
 SELECT * FROM artists 
 WHERE name in (SELECT group FROM members WHERE "end" IS NOT NULL  AND ROWNUM = 1);
```

as end is reserve word so use doube quote

Answer (score 0):

seems you have wrong closing parentesys  missing inner rownum = 1

```
SELECT * 
FROM artists 
WHERE name = (
    SELECT group 
    FROM members 
    WHERE end IS NOT NULL 
    AND ROWNUM = 1
    ORDER BY DATEDIFF(millisecond, end_g, start_g)
    ) 
    OR end IS NULL
```